# Recovery of deleted files from an iPad 2

Tags: ios, ipad, encryption, data-recovery

I'm trying to recover a book (actually, just a video in the book) made by Book Creator on an iPad 2.

The book was deleted and is no longer in recently deleted items.

As far as I understand it is not possible to recover deleted files because of the encryption, but I've read that in the earlier version of iOS, files made by third party apps were not encrypted. So, I'm wondering if there's a chance that the file is not encrypted as it was made a long time ago. The current iOS version is 9.3.5.

I don't have any backups.

The iPad hasn't really been used since I deleted the book, so it's probably not overwritten.

I don't want to spend $$$ on getting it back so I'm looking for some kind of software that allows me to scan the iPad for the file. Does anyone know if a solution exists?